# how to detect bad files msword and pdf before indexing

Tags: pdf, solr, ms-word, lucene, apache-tika

I try to index many files msword and pdf using solr-5.4.1 ;
In solr logg I get only the description of ERROR not the file who cause the Error;
 how to get a list of files are corrupt and Tika cannot index them; AND even if solr try index corrupt file and fail how force solr to continue indexing the next file ,because in handler DIH of solr I wrote in tika_data_config.xml onError="skip" or onError="continue" dont work because the indexation stop when tika try index the first corrupt file.

Comment: Run Tika against the file first before indexing?

Comment: how to run tika in solr core using data import handler?